# How to establish a secure websocket connection to a node server using self-signed certs?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, websocket, ssl-certificate

I've got an HTTPS webpage that won't let me connect to an insecure websocket, which I was using to communicate with a node sever, so I'm trying to migrate my node server to https.  The client-side https page was given to me to integrate my previously insecure page with, so I don't know anything about the certs it's using, if that matters.

To connect to it, on the client side I was using `connection = new Websocket('ws://node_server_address')` which worked fine for insecure connections.  Now that the page uses https, I'm just using `connection = new Websocket('wss://node_server_address')`, which I hope is all I need to change on the client side.  However, with self signed certs on the node server, I get this error when I try to connect with Chrome:

`Websocket connection to 'wss://address' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

On Firefox all it tells me is that it can't connect to the server.  I've seen plenty of examples where they don't specify a CA at all and they supposedly work fine, so I'm hoping I don't have to mess with that. However, assuming the only solution is to specify some valid CA, how would I generate that for a self-signed certificate?

## Node server:

```
const https = require('https');
const WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    
let serverOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./self-signed.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./self-signed.cert"),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}

const server = https.createServer(serverOptions, (req, res) => { res.end('') });

server.listen(port, function() { /* Logging */ }

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer:server
});
```

Comment: Be it websocket or pure HTTPS your client still needs to do the TLS handshake which means validating the certificate, and hence having the proper CA. If your server is using a selfsigned certificate, it means you will get rejections in the browser until you install it as a CA or at least do an exception rule for the specific certificate, but this is to do per client. You would have far less trouble by using like a Let's Encrypt certificate for your server since its CA will be recognized by all clients.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Since posting this I did add the .crt to Chrome and Firefox's authorities; the Firefox error didn't change and the Chrome error changed to ERR_CERT_NAME_INVALID.  I looked into that and tried to generate a key with a SAN instead of a CN but the openssl command said something along the lines of it couldn't find the SAN extension.  Unfortunately at this time self-signed certs are the only option.

Comment: One example on how to handle SANs with openssl: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/91556/137710  Otherwise you need a specific configuration file and hardcoding the names in it. Or use the newest `-addext` option is openssl 1.1.1